# The meaning of a て-form verb at the end of this sentence

Tags: て-form, particle-って

There are many explanations of t-form at the end of the sentence on internet like:

1) Connecting to other clauses, or  if there is no continuation, expressing that you want to continue.[て form at end of phrase but not being used for requests](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/60762/%E3%81%A6-form-at-end-of-phrase-but-not-being-used-for-requests)

2) Expressing  "while" "when" or "although" [What is the use of て-form at the end of this sentence?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/51740/what-is-the-use-of-%E3%81%A6-form-at-the-end-of-this-sentence)

3) Short way to say ...てください [Using て form at the end of sentences](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/12026/using-%E3%81%A6-form-at-the-end-of-sentences)

4) Giving a reason [Why is there て form at the end of the sentence?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/48946/why-is-there-%E3%81%A6-form-at-the-end-of-the-sentence?rq=1)

However, I can't understand this dialogue:

> Bulma: あんた女の人みたことないの?

Haven't you ever seen a women?

> Goku: 人間みたのもはじめてだ

It's the first time I see a human too.

> 死んだじいちゃんがいってたぞ

My dead grandfather said/needed

> もしもおまえが女とであうことがあったらやさしくして**やれって**

If you, meeting a women, unite/live, while been able to treat her kindly /be able to treat her kindly!...

What is the meaning of the t-form on this one?

Thanks.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The te-form of the verb やる is やって. やれって is not a te-form but やれ (the imperative form of やる, which can conclude a sentence on its own) followed by って.

This って is a colloquial version of quotative-と, and it's used in relation to 言ってたぞ in the previous sentence.

> 死んだじいちゃんがいってたぞ。もしもおまえが女とであうことがあったらやさしくしてやれって。
>
> ≒ 死んだじいちゃんが「もしもおまえが女とであうことがあったらやさしくしてやれ」と言ってたぞ。
>
> My dead grandfather was saying this: "If you should meet a woman, be kind to her."

See:

- [と、て、って　Quoting Particle Usage](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/3913/5010)
- [What is って in どうかしらって?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/54773/5010)